# Why is gas transferred while transferring eth?

Tags: solidity, ether, gas

I was watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlPc3EW-nNA&list=PLO5VPQH6OWdVQwpQfw9rZ67O6Pjfo6q-p&index=39&t=59s

It shows 3 ways to transfer eth. I want to know why is gas transferred to the receiver?
Shouldn't the gas be paid to the transaction miners?

I am probably confused with 2-3 concepts here and mixed them up. Can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using call() to send ether to another contract, gas is transferred to the receiver contract in order to execute the fallback function.

For example:

```
contract ReceiverContract{
  receive() external payable {
    //When receive ethers, update state .... 
  }
}
```

`(bool success, bytes memory data) = receiverContract.call{value: 100}("");` will forward all the gasleft to the receiverContract.receive() function. In this case, it will use that gas to pay for the transaction miners to execute receive() function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understood. But this raises another question about how is the gas calculated while calling call()? In the video, he says **all gas**, what is this all gas while transferring eth using call()?

Comment: You can read more about how gas work [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/). Basically, gas is sent along every time you execute an transaction (execute smart contract's write function). Usually, gas is estimated before create transaction and it is the gas limit of that transaction. That is the gas that you paid in advance when using metamask. If a transaction may spend more gas than estimated and it may cause "run out of gas".

Comment: When use "transfer" or "send", a little of gas is forwarded to another contract, so they may run out of gas to pay for the receive() function. The "call()" in this case will forward all the gas so that the cost for receive() function is covered!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this made my doubts clear.